# Needs values from non-future function to complete

Tags: flutter

I'm implementing code for flutter web. In this function, I get the statement `print('We are here');` before I get the message `print('$success ${errorMessage}');` which causes a FATAL error as I need the request to be completed at first to get the current values of `success` & `errorMessage` . I tried the keyword wait but it did nothing. Please **HELP**.

```
Future<Either<String, void>> createAvailableService(
  String name, XFile image, String imageName) async {
String errorMessage = 'Something went wrong, please try again later.';
try {
  html.File imageFile = html.File([await image.readAsBytes()], image.path);
  var request = html.HttpRequest()
    ..open('POST', APIs.CREATE_AVAILABLE_SERVICE);
  var formData = html.FormData()..appendBlob('image', imageFile);
  formData.append('name', name);
  formData.append('image_name', imageName);
  request.send(formData);
  bool success = true;
  request.onLoad.listen((_) {
    if(request.status == 200){
      success = true;
    }
    else if(request.status == 400 || request.status == 500){
      errorMessage = jsonDecode(request.response.toString())['message'];
      success = false;
      print('$success ${errorMessage}');
    }
    else{
      success = false;
    }
  });
  print('We are here');
  return Left(errorMessage);
} catch (exception) {
  return Left(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Yes.  listen sets up a handler to be executed at a future time.  'we are here' will print long before request.onLoad completes.

Comment: Can a Completer help?  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html

Comment: @RandalSchwartz So, how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [asFuture](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription/asFuture.html)

```
await request.onLoad.listen((_) {
  if(request.status == 200){
    success = true;
  }
  else if(request.status == 400 || request.status == 500){
    errorMessage = jsonDecode(request.response.toString())['message'];
    success = false;
    print('$success ${errorMessage}');
  }
  else{
    success = false;
  }
}).asFuture();
print('We are here');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it gets stuck in it and doesn't go forward for next statements.

Comment: does your request ever ends?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Even after the response is got.

Comment: `asFuture` will not tell you when the `onData` callback is invoked.